# Reshift grants verification HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE fails

Tags: permissions, amazon-redshift, sql-grant

I'm fighting with Redshit grants with groups, schemas, default privileges.
When I try to check is everything is correct using the HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE

```
select tablename, 
   HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE('analyst', tablename, 'select') as select,
   HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE('analyst', tablename, 'insert') as insert,
   HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE('analyst', tablename, 'update') as update,
   HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE('analyst', tablename, 'delete') as delete, 
   HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE('analyst', tablename, 'references') as references 
from pg_tables
where schemaname='datalab'
order by tablename
```

I get this :

```
An error occurred when executing the SQL command:
select tablename, 
   HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE('analyst', tablename, 'select') as select,
   HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE('analyst', tablena...

[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: relation "dss__transaction" does not exist;

Execution time: 0.2s
1 statement failed.
```

What the hell is happening here ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tried this and the query failed on the first result from `pg_tables`. In my case it was because I needed to explicitly state which schema each table was in. This worked for me:

```
WITH cte AS 
(
SELECT schemaname+'.'+tablename AS table_name
FROM pg_tables
WHERE schemaname = 'datalab'
)
SELECT table_name, 
   HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE('analyst', table_name, 'select') AS select,
   HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE('analyst', table_name, 'insert') AS insert,
   HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE('analyst', table_name, 'update') AS update,
   HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE('analyst', table_name, 'delete') AS delete, 
   HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE('analyst', table_name, 'references') AS references 
FROM cte
ORDER BY table_name ASC;
```